# VueJS <script> Template - Prop is not defined in mustache brackets

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, v-for

New to VueJS, so any suggestions are welcome.

I'm trying to use Vue to create Bootstrap 4 navs. The following works fine:

```
var Tabs = new Vue({
    el: '#tabs',
    components: {
        'tab-view': TabView,
    },
    data: {     
        tabs: settings.tabs
    },
});

<div id='tabs'>
    <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
        <li class='nav-item' v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :tab='tab'>
            <a :id='tab' :index='index' :class='{ active: (tab == "app"), "nav-link": true}'>{{tab}}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However, when I try to separate it out into a template using script tags, it doesn't work--I receive a ReferenceError: tab is not defined:

```
var TabView = {
    template: '#tab-template',
    props: ['tab', 'index'],
};

<div id='tabs'>
    <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
        <template v-for="(tab, index) in tabs">
            <tab-view :tab='tab' :index='index'></tab-view>
        </template>
        <script type='text/x-template' id='tab-template'>
            <li class='nav-item'>
                <a :id='tab' :index='index' :class='{ active: (tab == "app"), "nav-link": true}'>{{tab}}</a>
            </li>
        </script>
    </ul>
</div>
```

HOWEVER, if I remove {{tab}}, it works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where you passing the props values i.e. tab, index

Comment: code you provide your whole code in order to test it

Comment: I suggest you take a look at bootstrap-vue. https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should actually have the `tab-template` outside of the `vue app div tag`, since its a part of the `TabView` component definition like this.

```
<script type='text/x-template' id='tab-template'>
    <li class='nav-item'>
       <a :id='tab' :index='index' :class='{ active: (tab == "app"), "nav-link": true}' >{{tab}}</a>
    </li>
</script>

<div id='tabs'>
    <ul class='nav nav-tabs'>
        <div  v-for="(tab, index) in tabs" :key="index">
            <tab-view :tab='tab' :index='index' ></tab-view>
        </div>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Its something like the how you have separately defined the component `var TabView` in the script from the main vue `var vm`, then used that as `'tab-view'` in the `vue vm`

```
var TabView = {
    template: '#tab-template',
    props: ['tab', 'index']

};


var vm= new Vue({
   el: '#tabs',
   components: {
      'tab-view': TabView,
   },
   data() {
      return{
         tabs:["Home","app","about"]
      }
   },
});
```

Comment: Thank you! Makes sense.